# Concatenation of variables inside PHP statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query database for a unique result, sentence (asked from SQL console) is ok and the argument I send to database is ok so must throw a result.

This is my query:

```
$cliente = mysql_fetch_assoc($mySQL->query("SELECT nombre FROM clientes WHERE rfc=(SELECT rfc FROM facturas WHERE rfc='".$numFactura."')"));
if (empty($cliente))
```

It's always empty cause there's an issue with the sentence, how should it be like?

Comment: That depends on what the `$mysql->query()` method returns.
If it returns a `resource` of type mysql then you can pass it to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$cliente = mysql_fetch_assoc($mySQL->query("SELECT nombre FROM clientes WHERE rfc=(SELECT rfc FROM facturas WHERE rfc='$numFactura')"));
if (empty($cliente))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your subquery returns more than one row, it will fail. Make sure it returns only one row. If not, try this.

```
SELECT nombre FROM clientes WHERE rfc IN (SELECT rfc FROM facturas WHERE rfc='".$numFactura."')
```

Comment: He's already only returning `rfc` from his sub-query. I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is. There is no issue if his sub-query returns more than one row since all the `rfc` on that resultset will be the same.

Comment: Yeah, thats true. He should actually do: "SELECT nombre FROM clientes WHERE rfc='". $numFactura . "')". But his original query can fail if the subquery returns multiple rows.

Comment: You are right, I thought we was using an `IN` for his sub-query instead of an `=`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query uses a subquery but your subquery is redundant.

```
'SELECT rfc FROM facturas WHERE rfc='".$numFactura."''
```

This only means it will return all `rfc` that are equal to `$numFactura`

Your SQL query could effectively be:

```
SELECT nombre FROM clientes WHERE rfc = "$numFactura"
```

However if you want to make sure it has a corresponding entry on the facturas table then your query should be:

```
SELECT c.nombre FROM clientes c JOIN facturas f USING (rfc) GROUP BY c.rfc;
```